# javascript error handling doesn't work

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm just trying to read from a textbox and check if the textbox contains only letters. But when i try to catch the error. nothing happens. the alert message works fine which means the if statement is executed correctly but the problem with the error handling. what am I doing wrong?

```
function validateSearchInput() {

    let searchBoxValue = document.getElementById('search-box').value
    let lettersOnlyPattern = (/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/);

    try {
        if (!lettersOnlyPattern.test(searchBoxValue)) {
            alert('this will pop-up');
            throw new Error('Please enter letters only');
        }

        location.href = "country.html"; 

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

thanks all

Comment: You’re saying nothing shows up in the browser console?

Comment: yeah. in the javascript console nothing shows up.

Comment: works fine for me          try {            
                    alert('this will pop-up');
                    throw new Error('Please enter letters only');          
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                }

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mz3depha/1/

Comment: Thanks guys, it works